# C# and WinObjc in the same project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winobjc

I'm looking at the new WinObjc SDK, and I really like it. I'm thinking about doing most of a project I'm working on in objective-c, but I need to access the COM ports. I'm assuming using C# would be the easiest way to do that. Can I mix WinObjc (Objective-C) and C# code in the same visual studio project and have them talk to each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For .Net and Visual Studio you can typically have as many languages as you want in a Solution. Withing a single assembly, you can have a single language.  The way it works for .Net projects is you typically have each one compiled to a different assembly (dll) and one references the other.  Then the one can call functions in the other, etc.

Yes, as many assemblies as you want.  You can have C#, VB.Net, F#, Cobal.net, etc. in one program/solution as long as you follow the one language to one assembly rule.

I hope that answers your question.